Subscription limits for topics in FCM
The FCM documentation states that From the server, you can subscribe or unsubscribe up to 1000 devices in a single request. If you provide an array containing more than 1000 registration tokens (devices), the request will fail with the error messaging/invalid-argument.
Another page says that Speed ​​of adding/removing subscriptions to a topic is limited to 3000 QPS per project.
Question. Is it 3000 QPS for 1000 devices (3,000,000,000 subscriptions/descriptions per second, which is unlikely), or is it 3 requests for 1000 devices.
